# Finding out which wifi AP the device used to access the network

Tags: ieee-802.11

Is it possible to find out the MAC Addr of AP the device used to connect the network? I can get the MAC address and IP address of the device(maybe notebook or smartphone), and I have to check the MAC address of the wifi device. (I'm not saying about the gateway address) There are lots of AP with same ESSID and different channels here, and I want to get which AP was used.

Comment: P.s. I have heard about monitoring mode, but I couldn't figure out how to monitor whole accessible network.

Comment: Which devices do you have?

Comment: AP bendors are Aruba and Cisco.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You have two answers which reference the BSSID, and while the BSSID is often a MAC address and uses the same format, it is not technically considered a MAC address. Or do you mean the MAC address of the wired interface on the AP? The context of the question can be just as important in getting the best answers as the question itself.

Comment: We monitor this type of request 24/7 with Cisco Prime which manages quite a few WLCs.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know which AP your computer is connected to.  You have two options.

1. Use inSSIDer to investigate your wireless network.  The network that you are connected will be indicated by the green wireless icon.
   [image]

   2 . Use built-in netsh command in Windows 7 or Windows 8
   To do so, go to your Command Prompt that you can find in Accessories or click on the Windows button (Windows 7) or press Windows button on keyboard (Windows 8), and then type cmd

Command Prompt will be listed in front of you.  Click on it and type the following command line

netsh wlan show interfaces

[image]

What you need to focus on is BSSID value.  This is the MAC address of the AP that you are being connected.  Now you can go check the MAC address on the APs’ information label to find out which one you are connected to.

please check thise link [Which Access Point am I connected to?](http://ephams.com/2013/06/09/howto-access-point-connected-to/)

Answer (score 2):

If your network uses 802.1x with Radius, you can also retrieve this information from the Called Station ID field in the Radius request. Even better, by default this will give you both the AP MAC and the SSID name the device connected to... very handy when debugging complex environments.

Answer (score 0):

The **BSSID** (basic service set identifier) is what you seek.  Numerous wireless troubleshooting apps (e.g., Wifi Analyzer) will show the associated BSSID.

Under Windows, you could locate the BSSID with:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps on User's Windows Machine as requested by member

**The BSSID (basic service set identifier) is what you seek. Numerous wireless troubleshooting apps (e.g., Wifi Analyzer) will show the associated BSSID.
Under Windows, you could locate the BSSID with:**

**netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid**

We will get below output. Copy Mac address from output & use coffer website to find which Access point vendor like how I used which can be seen in below coffer snap.

Mine is **Aruba networks**

Kindly use the link below to know your Access point vendor.

http://coffer.com/mac_find/

[image]--->

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to go the the MAC table of the switch that your access points are using. If the MAC address of the device you are seeking shows up on a port that has one of your APs, then you're in luck, and have found the device you're looking for!